# Add product thumbnail to user/%/purchased-files?

Tags: ubercart

I've managed to add an extra field in the Purchased Files page, as well as hide the address limit, however I cannot figure out how to actually get the product thumbnail in there, like there is on the cart page. Below is what I'm working with so far, any ideas how to get the image associated with that file in the empty field?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/7T40GdX.png]

Answer (score 1):

You need to change page callback for path `user/%/purchased-files` in `hook_menu_alter()` and your custom callback should be based on code of `uc_file_user_downloads()` function, you need to change it, add new column with product image. I guess you need to change query in that function to get more data from 'uc_file_products' table about the product id, and based on that you can get all product info etc

Comment: I had to add an extra col into uc_file_products to hold the image, as there wasn't one before, and Ubercart doesn't seem to associate files with items purchased, presumably because you could possibly get the same file by purchasing multiple files. This is a hack-ish way to do this, but it works for me since I'm not planning on updating ubercart.

edit: posted as an answer, I'm running up against the character limit rapidly.